# How should this navigation be handled?

Tags: accessibility, scaling

I'm slightly worried about the navigation of an upcoming project. I feel it may be too crowded and could cause some sort of confusion. Although, I would like to point out that the my partner in this project wants the menu to be a "one click get anywhere" sort of navigation.

My problem with that is scaling, and I'm trying to find a more elegant solution.

Here is what I came up with

[image]

Dashboard will show notifications, while the projects menu is showing active projects the user is partaking in. Within each project there are sequences and within each sequence there are shots.

Personally, I've never been a fan of left navigations, but my question is: For page-scaling purposes is this something you'd find as an elegant solution? I'm also concern with whether this is easy to read or not (excluding the capital words, I don't like capital words; I put it there because I thought it would allow more distinction between projects). And yes, this would have an overflow of y if it were to expand bigger than the max width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of designs/applications using same approach:

**Example 1**

[image]

**Example 2**

[image]

Don't you think your first column is too empty? You can simplify the layout a bit combining both ideas (tree & switch) and use only one tree or simplified accordion.

**Simplified tree**

[image]

**Accordion**

[image]

Finally, there is a way to make this approach a bit more flexible:

[image]